# Adding an individual array list item to individual tile

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am currently trying to place individual items within an array list into individual tiles within a inventory GUI. All the tiles are set up and I can display each array list item individually within the console line.

This is the simple GUI:
[image: Simple GUI using tiles]

This is my attempt so far.

```
HBox itemTile[] = new HBox[31];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete Item");
        deleteButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            displayItems2(); //temp info to console - delete item code to be added
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item has been deleted", null, 1);
        });

        itemTile[i] = new HBox(new Label("Item: " + i + "   "));
        itemTile[i].setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
        itemTile[i].setPadding(new Insets(5));
        itemTile[i].getChildren().add(deleteButton);
        itemTile[i].setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        itemTile[i].setStyle("-fx-background-color: #e5efff; -fx-border-color: black;");
        this.getChildren().add(itemTile[i]);
    }
}

    private void displayItems2(){
        this.getChildren().removeAll(this.getChildren());
        displayInvStructure();
        ArrayList<String> descs = InventoryManager.getInstance().getItemDescriptions();
        for (int i = 0; i < descs.size(); i++) {
            String retString = descs.get(i);
               System.out.println("Array item is = " + " " + i + " " + retString);
               }
        //If i = itemTile[i]
        //Add retString to itemTile[i]
    }
```

How do I place each individual `retString` into each tile using the `itemTile[i]`?

I'm relatively new to coding and Java, so I have a sneaking suspicion I am over complicating things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign values to the `itemTile` array inside a method like `displayItems2`, there are two possibilities: 1) pass a reference to `itemTile` into `displayItems2` or 2) make `itemTile` a class member.

*Example 1 (pass a reference):*

```
private void displayItems2(HBox itemTile) {
    // [...]
    itemTile[i] = descs.get(i);
}
```

*Example 2 (class member):*

```
class MyClass {

    // [...]
    HBox itemTile;

    // [...]
    private void displayItems2() {
       // [...]
       itemTile[i] = descs.get(i);
    }
}
```